# Use echo to create a bash fils

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, echo

I wanted to make a one-liner that would create an executable. It's for a quick guide I' making for a friend, so that it would be an easy copy-paste job.

I have this:

```sh
export FILE=spotify; [ -f ~/.local/bin/$FILE ] && echo "File $FILE already exists. Couldn't create it..."; [ -f ~/.local/bin/$FILE ] || { echo $"#!/bin/sh\nflatpak run com.spotify.Client" > ~/.local/bin/$FILE; chmod +x ~/.local/bin/$FILE; echo "Successfully created $FILE" }
```

However I am stuck on `echo "#!/bash/sh"` which causes "event not found"...

Any ideas how to overcome that?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: `printf '#!/bin/sh\n....'`

Comment: Why are you `exporting` FILE?  `chmod` is certainly not going to use that, nor is `echo`.  Just set the variable.

Comment: I'm new to bash scripting. I thoght that export is mandatory. Thank you for that suggestion!

Comment: It seems a `;` is missing before the ending `}`

Answer (score 2):

In a Bash interactive shell the exclamation mark is used for searching the Bash history. Specifically, it replaces the string after the exclamation mark with the first entry in the history which matches that string. If there is no such entry, you get the symptom you're seeing.

The solution is to use a [*single-quoted string*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes).

Comment: Use a single-quoted string. Escaping the exclamation mark doesn't work right inside double-quotes (it leaves the backslash as part of the string).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, that solved it!That's interesting. I will have to do my research about the difference between quotes in bash.